# Binding of Multiple DataGrid Column Header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, wpfdatagrid

I came across this code sample at [TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22012.binding-of-datagrid-column-header.aspx) witch shows how to bind a single column header title and its corresponding columns data :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.HeaderNameText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and the DataContext of the DataGrid is set like so :

```
Data data = new Data();
data.HeaderNameText = "Header2";
data.Items = new List<string>() { "Item1", "Item2" };
DataContext = data;
```

the Data class structure is as follow :

```
public class Data
{
    public string HeaderNameText { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

my question is how to Bind the DataGrid ItemSource to multiple columns data :

```
List<Data> data=new List<Data>();
```

i am expecting to get a column for every data element in the above list, so how to achieve that?

Comment: If you're going to use a list of `Data` objects then you'll have multiple `Items` as well which makes little sense to me. Wouldn't it be more sensible to have a list of objects which have the value and column header set individually?

Comment: the number of columns is a changing factor, that can't be set statically(the header title also) !

Comment: Are you saying the number of columns varies between rows in the same `ItemsSource`?  Or simply that the number of columns in the `ItemsSource` isn't known ahead of time?  If the former, you're going to have to manage the set of columns as the rows/records come in.

Answer (score 1):

Given approach defines just one column

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn ...>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

For multiple columns you'll have to define it multiple times

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn ...>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn ...>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn ...>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If you define columns like this

```
public class Data
{
    public string[] HeaderNameText { get; set; } // array, list, etc.
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

then binding will be something like

```
{Binding DataContext.HeaderNameText[0] ...}
{Binding DataContext.HeaderNameText[1] ...}
```

etc.

Comment: The number of columns could change depends on the data.Count(), i don't want to define them statically in the xaml, but i need to define a data template that will apply on each columns!

Comment: Then given approach won't work. You can either use `AutoGenerateColumns = true` and supply column template (I seen somewhere here such approach) or generate `Columns` dynamically. Both required some code behind. Use search, to example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1983033/1997232) (keywords are `wpf datagrid column dynamically`).